# Define and write in a file as right-align by default

Tags: visual-c++

To continue, I have this code:

```
CString m_sName=L"عباس";
int size_needed=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
std::string utf8_string(size_needed, 0);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, &utf8_string[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);

FILE *file;
open_s(&file, "bid.txt", "wb");
fprintf(file, "\%s", utf8_string.c_str());
fclose(file);
```

When I run the program and open bid.txt, I can see:

```
`عباس`
```

It's Ok, but as you probably know, the Farsi (Persian) language writes from right to left. So, I have to adjust my file as a right-align file. In other words, how can I adjust my file that my data can be written and shown from right to left, automatically?

I would appreciate if you can help me.

I try to adjust my file(bid.txt). but it just work manually!